# The jumping problem when rolling a Reuleaux triangle

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, animation, rotation

I'm making an animation of a [Reuleaux triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reuleaux_triangle) rolling on a straight line like this
[image: rolling Reuleaux triangle]

The animation generated by my code is not continuous. Is there a simple way to eliminate jumping?

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{reuleaux, s},
  reuleaux[t_] = {-Cos[Pi/3 (1 + 2 Floor[3 t])] +  Sqrt[3] Cos[Pi/6 + Pi t + Pi/3  Floor[3 t]],
  -Sin[Pi/3 (1 + 2 Floor[3 t])] + Sqrt[3] Sin[Pi/6 + Pi t + Pi/3  Floor[3 t]]};
  s[t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Norm[reuleaux'[s]], {s, 0, t}];
  ParametricPlot[{s[u], 0} + (reuleaux[t] - reuleaux[u]).RotationMatrix[ArcTan @@ (reuleaux'[u])] // Evaluate,
  {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 7}, {-1, 2}}]
  ], {u, 0.001, 1 + 0.001}]
```

[image: animation with jump]

Reference link:
[On rolling polygons and Reuleaux polygons](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1628699)
[formula-to-create-a-reuleaux-polygon](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2279568/formula-to-create-a-reuleaux-polygon)
[How to roll a graph on the y-axis](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/242180/how-to-roll-a-graph-on-the-y-axis)
[How to plot a bicycle with square wheels](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/212962/how-to-plot-a-bicycle-with-square-wheels)

Comment: The problem stems from the fact that the rotation angle `ArcTan @@ (reuleaux'[t])` is not a continuous function of `t`, which in turn stems from the fact that your parametrization of the curve has a discontinuous derivative at the corners.  So when you get to one of the corners, the animation skips from rolling along one curve to rolling along the next curve, without pivoting around the corner in between these motions.  Not immediately sure how to fix this, but I'll think on it further.

Answer (score 5):

Daniel Huber's code seems to let the points and edges slide a little.  In order to ensure no slippage, you need to use the perimeter of the shape: each arc has length $\pi/3$, so the distance between successive vertex rotations should be $\pi/3$.

This code is crude but gets the job done

```
With[{prims=Circle@@@({CirclePoints@3/√3,{1,1,1},{{2,3},{4,5},{0,1}}π/3}\[Transpose])},
Animate[Graphics@With[{mθ=Mod[θ,2π/3]},With[{tr={⌊3θ/(2π)⌋π/3,0}+
If[mθ<π/3,{mθ(π-√3)/π,1-Cos[π/6-mθ]/√3},{(2π-√3)/6-Cos[mθ]/√3,Sin[mθ]/√3}]},
{Point@tr,TranslationTransform[tr]@*RotationTransform[π/6-θ]/@prims,
Line/@{{{-1,1},{5,1}},{{-1,0},{5,0}}},Point@{π#/3-1/(2√3),0}&/@Range[0,4]}]],
{θ,0,7π/3},AnimationDirection->ForwardBackward]]
```

and you get something like

[image: rolling1]

Answer (score 2):

With code from the Wolfram Demo project for a Reuleaux triangle from `https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ARotatingReuleauxTriangle/` and some small changes:

```
angle[vec_] := 
 Arg[First[vec] + I*Last[vec]] + If[Last[vec] >= 0, 0, 2*Pi]

centerpath[t_] := 
  Piecewise[{{{1 + Cos[Mod[t, 2 Pi/3] + 7 Pi/6] + 
       Sqrt[3]/3*Sin[Mod[t, 2 Pi/3] + 7 Pi/6], 
      1 + Sin[Mod[t, 2 Pi/3] + 7 Pi/6] + 
       Sqrt[3]/3*Cos[Mod[t, 2 Pi/3] + 7 Pi/6]}, 
     0 <= Mod[t, 2 Pi/3] < Pi/6},
    {{-1 - Sin[Mod[t, 2 Pi/3] + Pi] - 
       Sqrt[3]/3*Cos[Mod[t, 2 Pi/3] + Pi], 
      1 + Cos[Mod[t, 2 Pi/3] + Pi] + 
       Sqrt[3]/3*Sin[Mod[t, 2 Pi/3] + Pi]}, 
     Pi/6 <= Mod[t, 2 Pi/3] < Pi/3},
    {{-1 - Cos[Mod[t, 2 Pi/3] + 5 Pi/6] - 
       Sqrt[3]/3*Sin[Mod[t, 2 Pi/3] + 5 Pi/6], -1 - 
       Sin[Mod[t, 2 Pi/3] + 5 Pi/6] - 
       Sqrt[3]/3*Cos[Mod[t, 2 Pi/3] + 5 Pi/6]}, 
     Pi/3 <= Mod[t, 2 Pi/3] < Pi/2},
    {{ 1 + Sin[Mod[t, 2 Pi/3] + 2 Pi/3] + 
       Sqrt[3]/3*Cos[Mod[t, 2 Pi/3] + 2 Pi/3], -1 - 
       Cos[Mod[t, 2 Pi/3] + 2 Pi/3] - 
       Sqrt[3]/3*Sin[Mod[t, 2 Pi/3] + 2 Pi/3]}, 
     Pi/2 <= Mod[t, 2 Pi/3] < 2 Pi/3}}];

reuleaux[s_] := Module[{a, b, c},
  a = centerpath[s] + Sqrt[3]/3*2*{Cos[-s], Sin[-s]};
  b = centerpath[s] + Sqrt[3]/3*2*{Cos[-s + 2 Pi/3], Sin[-s + 2 Pi/3]};
  c = centerpath[s] + Sqrt[3]/3*2*{Cos[-s + 4 Pi/3], Sin[-s + 4 Pi/3]};
  Graphics[{LightGray,
    Disk[a, 2, {angle[b - a], angle[b - a] + Pi/3}],
    Disk[b, 2, {angle[c - b], angle[c - b] + Pi/3}],
    Disk[c, 2, {angle[a - c], angle[a - c] + Pi/3}],
    Black,
    Circle[a, 2, {angle[b - a], angle[b - a] + Pi/3}],
    Circle[b, 2, {angle[c - b], angle[c - b] + Pi/3}],
    Circle[c, 2, {angle[a - c], angle[a - c] + Pi/3}],
    PointSize[.02], Black,
    Point[a],
    Point[b],
    Point[c],
    Point[(a + b + c)/3],
    Line[{{1, -1}, {1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, -1}, {1, -1}}]},
   Axes -> True]
  ]
```

And the addition of the x- movement we can create the following animation:

```
Animate[Graphics[{Translate[reuleaux[s][[1]], {Sqrt[3] s, 0}],
   Line[{{{-2, -1}, {12, -1}}, {{-2, 1}, {12, 1}}}]} , 
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 12}, {-1.2, 1.2}}, ImageSize -> 500], {s, -0.1 , 
  2 Pi}]
```

[image]